# Golang global setup for all tests (within same and other sub modules).

Tags: go

I generally try to run the command `go test ./...` for CI/CD pipeline which used to run all test cases among all the subdirectories.

But I recently refactored my code to take config file path from flag parsing and then reading and initializing all variables(required before server startup).This change required to remove all initialization code from 
`init function -> custom function` which will be called from main.

Now everything relates is done but all test cases are not working as I need to call all the custom functions from somewhere.

I tried using the TestMain feature but I think it is only working for the same module and all test cases are failing.

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) { 
    mySetupFunction()
    retCode := m.Run()
    myTeardownFunction()
    os.Exit(retCode)
}
```

Need help to know how can I create a global test setup or would like to know is there any other better way for above-mentioned refactoring.

I have my modules structure as follow

```
A
    B
    C
    D
        E
            F
        G
            H
    I
main.go
```

where parent module is A which contains main.go and various others module some nested to the deep level and all of them are having their own test cases

Comment: Just copy paste `TestMain` into each package you need global setup/teardown? What you want probably isn't possible since packages are totally independent of one another, go doesn't see a heirarchy. It seems repetitive but it's going to take you five minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://pkg.go.dev/testing). I believe what you are looking for is `func TestMain(m *testing.M)`.

It is basically setup/teardown method. Go executes the tests "within" that that method. So you just need to set it up. You don't have to call it in you tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you came from an `init` function, you could always make a test package that has the `init` code you'd like to run for your unit tests, and import that for the side effect.

Make pkg called `initializetest`, implement the `init()` function, then in all your test files, import it like so:

```golang
import (
  _ "project/path/initializetest"
)
```

---

I don't totally like this, as init() side effects can be a pain to debug. Calling the setup explicitly for each unit test would be better.